# LVM created in CentOS 7 now cant view free space?

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

Created an LVM when installing CentOS 7.

I have a 1TB drive. I still had about 800 GB free. I cant see those 800GB anywhere.

```
[root@mimir user]# df -h
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl_mimir-root            50G  1.4G   49G   3% /
devtmpfs                            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               1.9G  8.6M  1.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          1014M  178M  837M  18% /boot
/dev/sda1                           200M  9.5M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/cl_mimir-var_log        4.7G   45M  4.7G   1% /var/log
/dev/mapper/cl_mimir-home            47G   33M   47G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/cl_mimir-var_lib_mysql  4.7G   62M  4.6G   2% /var/lib/mysql
tmpfs                               370M     0  370M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                               370M     0  370M   0% /run/user/0
[root@mimir user]
[root@mimir user]# pvscan
PV /dev/sda3   VG cl_mimir        lvm2 [113.34 GiB / 12.00 MiB free]
Total: 1 [113.34 GiB] / in use: 1 [113.34 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
[root@mimir user]#
```

What am I doing wrong? How could I use that 800GB to extend a volume? Why can't I see it?

Comment: You can't see it because you haven't looked for it. Try something relevant, such as `pvdisplay`. And please read the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/index.html).

Comment: Another relevant command is `lsblk` particularly useful because it will show both partitions and lvs.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your free space using command "fdisk -l". It will show similar output like below.

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000aec37

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1   *        2048    41929649    20963801   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/docker-202:1-33866504-pool: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes, 20971                                                                                        5200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 65536 bytes
```

Please follow article below to create partition using LVM. 
http://www.tecmint.com/create-lvm-storage-in-linux/